# Example of CAT($k$) space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, metric-spaces, alexandrov-geometry

Good time of day. I repeat the question from MSE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464888/question-about-example-of-catk-space) because no response has been received.Question is the following: It's written in wiki in examples of CAT($k$) spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space) that the closed subspace $X$ of $\mathbb E^3$ (where $\mathbb E^3$ is a 3-dimensional Euclidean space) given by $X=\mathbb E^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z)|x>0, y>0, z>0\}$ equipped with the induced length metric is not a  CAT($k$) space for any $k$. There was the following advice in comment of MSE: consider triangle with vertices on the border: $(x,0,0)$, $(0,y,0)$, $(0,0,z)$. In this case as I understand I need to use CAT($k$) inequality and the following proposition: geodesic metric space $X$ is said to be CAT($k$) space if every geodesic triangle in $X$ with perimeter less then $2D_k$ satisfies the CAT($k$) inequality (Where $D_k$ is a diameter). If I'm right why we have geodesic triangle in $X$ with perimeter less than $2D_k$ which is not satisfied by this CAT($k$) inequality?

I want to understand how it all works.

If you don't mind can you please explain why it's not a CAT($k$) space in more details?

Thank you!

Comment: The triangle $\triangle$ with the vertices you list can be chosen to have small diameter. Consider the comparison triangle $\tilde\triangle$ in the curvature $k$ model plane (a sphere if $k>0$) and compare the corresponding angles of $\triangle$ and $\tilde\triangle$.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek Thank you for your comment. How does the curvature influence  the result? If you don't mind can you please explain this in answer in more details? Because I can't find examples of application these principles and theorems to certain examples

Comment: In this example you are checking a definition of curvature $\le k$. If you read some textbook on the subject, e.g. those mentioned in the wiki page you mention, you will find more examples and applications.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek thank you for your time. Unfortunately, these examples were mentioned in wiki without any details. I'm studying math without tutors and sometimes it's sophisticated for me to understand any things. Possibly it's a trivial question. I don't understand why distances between points in geodesic triangle are not less or equal than distances between corresponding points in comparison triangle. Also I try to draw picture in $E^3$

Comment: By the way, it is easy to prove that if a polyhedral space is CAT(к), then it is CAT(0). So you should not worry about к.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin Something the same I read in one article. It was written in this article: if a Banach space CAT($k$) for some $k \in R$ then it is necessarily a Hilbert space and CAT($0$) space. I'm not sure about this. If you don't mind can you please explain why distances between points in geodesic triangle are not less or equal than distances between corresponding points in comparison triangle?

Comment: The statement about Banach space is not related. It follows since the CAT-comparison implies the parallelogram identity.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin thank you for your explanation of this moment.Please, can you give me a hint about angles of triangles and distances? How can I see this? Possibly is there a graphical picture of this situation?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin thank you for your help and for your time. You help me a lot! Sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: The space contains arbitrarily small geodesic bigons, which is impossible for a CAT(k) space.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan thank you for interesting comment.  Can you please explain this moment in more details? I haven't met this concept yet. What are small geodesic bigons in this space?

Comment: As I said you need to read a textbook. If I may, I suggest Burago-Burago-Ivanov as a most friendly exposition. Tutors are not needed but it will be a substantial time investment. At this point you don't seem to know basis definitions, which is where your questions originate.

Comment: @Igor Belegradek Thank you for your reference I will see this book. Yes I have small experience in this field. These spaces interested me because they are any kind of generalization of  Riemannian space as I understand.

Comment: @UserIn: Think of the boundary of your space. Prove that it is isometric to a cone of revolution in $R^3$ with the total angle at the apex equal $3\pi/2$. A geodesic bigon is a pair of points connected by distinct geodesics (of equal length) connecting these points. Could you find such a bigon on on cone of revolution? If not, you are not ready for the material you are reading.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the issues mentioned in @IgorBelegradek's comment